# Data Structures recurrence relation

Tags: data-structures, recursive-query

I need help and your tips to answer this kind of question because I'm lost...
this is the question:
there are n letters, each letter has its box mail.
f(n) = the number of ways to put every letter in the wrong box mail.
I need to find a recursive algorithm.

so this is my thoughts so far:
f(n = 1) = 0
f(n = 2) = 1
for the n letter you have (n-1) options to put the letter in the wrong box mail.
so maybe it should be something like : 
n-1 * (f(n-1))

I don't know if I'm thinking in the right direction, and how more or less should I think. 
also if you have a resource that can help me I will be more than happy.
this is the options:
(the fourth option is that none of the answers is right)
[click here to see the answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTyoT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `n=4` case.  We have four boxes at first.  We need to pick the box for the letter 1 from `n-1` choices. For the sake of explanation, let's say we picked the box 2.

```
1  2  3  4
  /
1  2  3  4
```

Now there are two possibilities.

1. letter 2 is mailed in box 1.  Then, we are left with 3 and 4 for both boxes and letters.  So, there are `f(2)` ways.
2. letter 2 is mailed in a box other than 1.  Then, we are supposed to look for a way of arranging letters 1, 3, 4 and boxes 2, 3, 4, with a condition that letter 1 and 2 are not paired. That's the same situation as arranging three letters and boxes with the same set of numbers. So there are `f(3)` such ways.

Generalizing this logic, `f(n) = (n-1) * (f(n-2) + f(n-1))`.